# Are sunny, warm days a pipe-dream in Venice/Rome in late November?

Tags: weather-and-climate, italy, rome, venice

We are taking our first family trip to Europe this Thanksgiving (Nov 16 - 27th).  Our itinerary is 3 days in Venice, 3 days in Florence and remaining in Rome (leave from Rome).

Anyone have an idea what the weather will be like?  My agent said she was there at that time and wore a t-shirt and no jacket.

I hope to brush up on my first real travel photography (using more than a 35mm wind and click) so I'm praying for some sunny days.

Comment: Does anyone think we will need coats in any of these cities?  Or would thermal underwear and a couple layers with a hoodie be fine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was in Venice last year on 27th Nov. Based on my experience on that day :

- You definitely need to wear jacket. It was around 6-8 Celcius. I put some of my photos below. As you can see, all the people wear jackets.
- On that day, it was sunny. I love photography as you do, and my photos in Venice were my best photos during my trip in Europe.

However there's a possibility of [Acqua Alta](http://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Travel-g187870-c151727/Venice:Italy:Acqua.Alta.And.Flooding.In.Venice.html) (flood) during November, which usually dissapears within hours. But if like you said you want to stay 3 days in Venice, your probability of having at least 1 sunny day is greater.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I would love to see the video.  And any other videos you have in Venice, Florence, Pisa, or Rome.  :-)  Can you put them on YouTube?

Comment: Also, I can handle cool to cold but when you throw in rain, it gets bad.  Were you able to sit outside any?  Like some cafe sipping coffee outside comfortably?  I would hate to have to eat all meals inside.

Comment: I'm still trying to find the video. However I have put some photos, to give you a clearer perspective of the weather. And because it was cold, we drank coffee anywhere I can, outside. Try Italian hot chocolate. I don't have any video in other city.

Comment: On the matter of acqua alta, those bench-table things people are sitting on in the first picture are for walking on when the water gets high. Just to give an idea how high it gets.

Comment: That is awesome!  It looks cold but doable.  Plus, walking keeps you warm.  You know, I bet I could do a search on Flickr for photos with a timestamp and location.

Answer (score 5):

On average, November in Venice is relatively chilly (average daily high is 11°C) and with a good chance of rain as it is the wettest month ([weather.com](http://www.weather.com/outlook/travel/vacationplanner/vacationclimatology/monthly/ITXX0085)). Still, as with most of Europe, the weather fluctuates and you might experience better (or worse) weather. You will however definitely need to pack for chilly weather.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give a definite answer for late November, but having been in Tuscany and Rome several times in late December, you do need more than a T-shirt. Venise also is cold in Winter with wet wind from the sea.